# How do I make APIManagement Service Logger deploy before the Application insights Resource?

Tags: api, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I am trying to make the following ARM deploy a APIM service logger, however the service logger starts to deploy before the app insights resource and fails, the app insights resource is in a seperate template. I have added a dependson statement and thought that would do the job but that did'nt work either. Also the code below actually works if the app insights is already deployed.

does anyone have any pointers?

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers",
      "name": "[concat(variables('apiManagementInstanceName'), '/', parameters('appInsightsName'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
      "properties": {
        "loggerType": "applicationInsights",
        "description": "Logger resources to APIM",
        "credentials": {
          "instrumentationKey": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('appInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
        }
      }
     "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appInsightsName'))]"
      ]

    }
```

also tried depending on both the APIM and app insights

```
"dependsOn": [
            //"[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('apiManagementInstanceName'))]"
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appInsightsName'))]"
          ],
```

Comment: Is that you use seperate template to deploy Azure application insight and logger?

Comment: yes, so the logger is in the API management template and the app insights is in a seperate template, they are both linked templates from a master template.

Comment: Since the logger resource depends on application insight and they are in different template, you need to deploy the application insight template at first. Otherwise, you will get error.

Comment: Would i do that on the depends on statement on the master template?

Comment: As far as I knew, when we use `dependsOn` in your template, it will look for the resource in your subscription. If the resource does not exit in your subscription, you will get error.

Comment: Thanks @JimXu, your suggestions actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked templates to reference another template file and define dependencies on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates#linked-template